# CSS - Force Text to Fill n Lines

Tags: css, text

Bit of an add question, couldn't find anything on it.

I have some divs with text in them, they have a 50% width.
How can I force the text to break where necessary to form 3 balanced lines?

Basically here is an example:
Currently:

```
I am some text la la la
Text
```

What I want:

```
I am some
text la la
la Text
```

So the text wraps and balances out 3 lines.

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

TIA.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by "break"? You don't want the text to spill over onto new lines? Or do you?

Comment: Edited to explain hopefully. I want the text to evenly fill 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can add height to div in css.

```
.div{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 4.5em;   
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: This won't force the text to form 3 even lines?

Comment: That only specifies height... he asked about width.

Answer (score 0):

The text is expanding to occupy the space of the element containing it, aka `50%`. If you want the text to have a smaller width and preserve the size of the `div` element you'll need to have to nest the text in another element with a different width.

I'm sure if you looked hard enough you'd find a weird hack that made the plain text constricted to a different width but I believe it just makes the most sense to use another element.

```
<div>
  <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
</div>

div {
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  width: 100px;
}
```